# Using JQuery to change a drop-down menu's selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do i go about creating some JQuery code which will change the selected value of an  menu.

On my page i have created a drop down menu like so:

```
<select id="select_Day">
    <option value="Monday">Monday</option>
    <option value="Tuesday">Tuesday</option>
    <option value="Wednesday">Wedsnesday</option>
    <option value="Thursday">Thursday</option>
    <option value="Friday">Friday</option>
    <option value="Saturday">Saturday</option>
    <option value="Sunday">Sunday</option>
</select>
```

The page i have the menu on is then being passed values from a form on another page, below is how i retrieve the values:

```
<?php
    $day = $_GET['day'];
?>
```

I then copy the values of the PHP variables to some javascript variables:

```
$(document).ready(function(event){
    var day = <?php echo $day ?>; 
});
```

How would i then change the drop-down menus selected value to that of the $day variable, so for example, if the page is passed the value 'Friday' how would i then have that option as the selected choice?

Comment: Why not output the right html? So if Wednesday is selected make the option-tag like this: <option selected value="Wednesday">Wedsnesday</option>.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323607/use-jquery-select-an-option

Comment: BTW if you leave out the value-attribute, the value will automatically become the visible text.

Comment: Like edwin said, you already have the information about which day should be selected. Use `selected="selected"` though, opposed to just `selected`. Changing it after the DOM has been created through jQuery isn't necessary. Also, you might want to keep your code separated instead of using PHP within JavaScript, ideally keeping the JavaScript separated from the rest altogether in a .js file. If you need information from the DOM, use the jQuery selectors to get it.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(event){
    var day = <?php echo $day ?>; 
    $('#select_Day').val(day);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

It is better to put selected="selected" in the html of whatever option you want to preselected then to use jQuery as it'll work even in old browsers or if javascript is turned off. You can try something like this:

```
       <?php 
$arr = array('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday','Friday','Saturday','
    Sunday');
        for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
           $selected = ($arr[$i] == $day) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
           echo "<option value=\"{$arr[$i]}\" {$selected}>{$arr[$i]}</option>";
        }
?>
```