# Select option in html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-select

I have select tag with a lot of options inside. I have to set selected some option with text value = **%value%** after page is loaded (jquery). How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery : check if select contains option?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744289/jquery-check-if-select-contains-option) or [Use jquery select an option](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323607/use-jquery-select-an-option), depending on whether you want to select by value or by text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
$("option[value='%value%']").attr("selected",true);
```

Comment: Umm, you have true wrapped in quotes. You should either lose the quotes, or do what I did in my answer `.attr('selected, 'selected')`

Comment: `selected` is a boolean attribute, to validate it either needs to be present, or have it's value set to itself (`selected="selected"`). That all being said: `selected="true"` will *work*, but is not **valid**.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('option[value=' + somevalue + ']').attr('selected', 'selected');
```